# How do I display only the parent page in the url

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls

My site is going to serve content that I want to keep hidden. It is set up like the example below.

```
site.com/parentPage1/ChildPage1
site.com/parentPage1/ChildPage2
site.com/parentPage1/ChildPageN
site.com/parentPage2/ChildPage1
site.com/parentPage2/ChildPage2
```

I'd like to keep the child page location hidden in the URL so that it displays like this.
"site.com/parentPage". The exact url is sensitive information that I don't want the public to be able to navigate back to without my assistance.

I only want this to happen whenever I'm serving WP child pages, so I can avoid issues with other pages, what i've tried so far in .htaccess has been not been maintainable and it certainly will not scale. I haven't seen anyone else try to achieve this, can anyone help?

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time achieving this... ..even if you end up managing it the child page slug will still be locatable by anyone even mildly tech/dev savvy.  As an alternative, why not swap out the content on the parent page using AJAX?

Comment: The pages I want to serve are just form data, I only want to keep them hidden to prevent my data from getting messed up. Serving with AJAX isnt a bad idea though.